# Xcode 10 simulator runtime is not available: runtime profile not found error

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

While trying to run the simulator with iOS 11 in Xcode 10 Version 10.1 (10B61), sometimes this error occurs:

"*The com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-4 simulator
runtime is not available.
runtime profile not found*"

[image: Xcode Simulator runtime is not available error]

The 11.4 simulator runtime is an external disk and it's well connected. Maybe that happens when I connect the external disk after opening the Xcode. How can I refresh the list of the available simulator runtime profiles?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Just run

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

to restart the Simulator service.

Comment: Do you have any insights on why this occurs? Is it an issue with `CoreSimulatorService`?

Comment: @EvanR No, don't know why that happened. Sorry

Comment: I wonder why this is not part of the install scripts on xcode updates