# xcode/simulator crash when viewing any storyboard for any project

Tags: xcode, xcode10

having an issue with Xcode10 - if I create a new single view project and click on the Main.storyboard or Launchscreen.storyboard Xcode notifies me of "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited."

By limited, it means non-existent. It isn't possible to do anything on the editor page. Looking at the error I get this:

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUnew.png)

> Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=IBAgent-iOS failed to launch, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc5cec94430 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to boot IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (46853B2D-B957-4F56-9B2F-F187C9ABDB4D, iOS 12.1, Shutdown)

Looking in my devices under CoreSimulator - I haven't got any with that UUID. This happens on every single project I attempt to create.

Xcode version is 10.1 (10B61) on Mojave. I cleaned the project, removed DerivedData, I have uninstalled Xcode and reinstalled (including all ~/Library & /Library preferences, caches, receipts etc) but none of these resolved the problem. I also reinstalled MacOS Mojave and then reinstalled Xcode, but again, this didn't solve the issue. I also manually deleted all simulator devices and readded. Again, nada - it's still trying to use that non-existent device: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x, even when I select iPhone8 as the editor Device.

[iPhone8 selected but error still exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRsvW.png)

I'm up the creek without a paddle. It looks like Xcode is trying to use a simulator device that doesn't exist. Does anyone know how I can rectify/fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some research. Some people had to rename the Xcode app. They renamed Xcode to Xcode10. Others renamed Xcode-beta to Xcode. Try that.

Comment: yep, tried that already (and set Locations accordingly). Same issue.

Comment: Did u change the deployment target

Comment: Sadly, yes. I even re-downloaded iOS 8 (supported by iPad 2) and changed the deployment to that to try and at least get it to retro-work, but no dice.

Comment: I should note, when I run the app with the simulator as the target (say, iPhone XR), it works just fine in the simulator. This is just in the Interface Builder I'm getting the issues. Unfortunately, that's kind of crucial for me.

Comment: Another thing that may help track the problem down - if you look in the original error - the Device UUID that launchd is trying to boot is '46853B2D-B957-4F56-9B2F-F187C9ABDB4D' - in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices there is no device with that UUID. If I could find where in Xcode this UUID is being set and stored, I may be able to solve the problem. Unfortunately, despite a OS reinstall, and several deep uninstalls of Xcode (inc receipts/preferences/caches etc) it persists, so there must be somewhere else where this is being stored that each diff Xcode install is looking at.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a few days, found an error in the CoreSimulator log that took me to [another SOF post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261256/xcode-10-simulator-runtime-is-not-available-runtime-profile-not-found-error).

Just run

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

to restart the Simulator service and that fixed everything for me.

Comment: that did nothing