# Could not create iPhone ... unknown runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I installed xcode 12.4 released on 26th Jan 21.

I have symlink /Library/Developer to external drive. My DerivedData and Archives also point to external drive.

None of the simulators are listed in the window, when I try to 'Add a new simulator' (I remember deleting them initially, some time before, but I have reinstalled xcode after cleaning everything multiple times) It gives an Error saying unknown runtime to whatever I select. OS version select box does not show any option and it is only 'download more simulator runtimes'

[image: Error]

Downloaded runtimes from components tab in settings as shown in screenshot, I can see the run time in (External Drive - symlink) /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

[image: Runtimes]

Tried restarting, reinstalling and these
[Xcode 10 simulator runtime is not available: runtime profile not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261256/xcode-10-simulator-runtime-is-not-available-runtime-profile-not-found-error)

[The iOS 13.0 simulator runtime is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462769/the-ios-13-0-simulator-runtime-is-not-available)

[iOS simulator is not launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296360/ios-simulator-is-not-launching)

Edit 1:

```
xcrun swift --version
```

Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0

```
xcode-select -p
```

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

```
sudo xcrun simctl list
```

CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.

Comment: "I have symlink /Library/Developer to external drive" I would suggest don't do that.

Comment: the folder takes 15gb space and unfortunately i don't have that much space, thats an SSD and everything else, CommandLineTools, seems to work just fine .

Comment: Command Line Tools is not evidence for anything. It just puts stuff into `/usr` and does not link back to Xcode. How about `xcrun swift --version`? Does that work? Also what does `xcode-select -p` say? Just curious.

Comment: edited question with output of these ... someone's old answer says symlinks works after xcode 11 in apple developer community ... will have to search again

Comment: Definitely the problem sounds like Xcode is not seeing the simulators. I can't guarantee that the symlinking works; it's lucky that it did, but now maybe it just doesn't. I recommend using DaisyDisk or similar to find something else large that you can remove from your hard disk and thus allow enough room to let these folders back on to the hard disk.

Comment: thanks @matt i will try what best i can do ... as runtimes are needed CoreSimulator directory takes hell lot of space ... xcode app itself takes 20gb ... i wish it would hav worked

Comment: Hi @matt please help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66008873/failed-to-initialize-simulator-device-set

Answer (score 1):

Here it worked for me:

Step 1 : Go to Windows -> Device and Simulators

Step 2 : Click on Simulator Tab and click the add button at the bottom

Step 3 : Add new Simulator. Select the Device Type, Select OS version as Download more simulators. Click Create.

Step 4 : Install at least one iOS version from all the series.

Step 5 : Once Installed. You Still won't be able to see it.

Step 6 : After all this Restart your Mac.

Step 7 : Open Xcode. You Should see the installed Simulators now.

Happy Coding.. :)